# SQL use function returned string in select where in(..) query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a function that returns a string with id's connected by comma, something like that:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fGetChildIdByPId] 
(
    @ID INT         
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @RET VARCHAR(1000)
    SET @RET = ''

    DECLARE CUR CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY FOR 
        SELECT ID FROM tControl WHERE parentID = @ID 
    OPEN CUR

    FETCH FROM CUR INTO @ID
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN
        SET @RET = @RET + CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR(10)) + ',' 
        + dbo.fGetChildIdByPId(@ID) 
        FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @ID
    END
    CLOSE CUR
    DEALLOCATE CUR   

    RETURN  @RET 
END
```

In another function I want to use the string returned from previous function in another select query like that:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ShouldOutput
( 
    @id int,  
    @gid int
)
returns int
as
begin
     declare @out int

     if exists(SELECT * FROM tControl 
         where id in (select [dbo].[fGetChildIdByPId](@id)) 
         and summaryIndex=1 and goodId = @gid)
         set @out = 1
     else 
        set @out = 0
return @out
end
```

But of course, there is the problem because the value of select [dbo].fGetChildIdByPId can't be cast to integer and can't be used in a query. I thought of using EXEC or sp_executesql but I can't use them in a function, only in stored procedures but I need a function, because I need to use the returned 1 or 0 value in another sql query. What is the easiest way to make the mentioned query work?

Comment: Maybe you should just tell us what you're trying to do... in simple English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't.

Your second function should take a table valued parameter - where that parameter is a table of values that you wish to use in the function - rather than a concatenated string.

To that end, your first function should return a table of values, not a string.

Comment: Worth stating that TVP's are only usable from SQL Server 2008 onward.

Answer (score 0):

While in an explicit IN function (where you define a set of results i.e. state IN (1, 2)) does use a comma separated list if you pass it a function that returns a comma separated list that wont work.

If you alter your first function to

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fGetChildIdByPId] 
(
    @ID INT         
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN 
    SELECT ID, GoodId FROM tControl WHERE parentID = @ID 
END
```

Then everything should work fine (not tested).